# Upper bound on discrepancy of two sums

Tags: inequality, upper-lower-bounds

Can you help upper bounding this?
\begin{equation}
\left|\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{m} a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{m} t_i} - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{m} b_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{m} s_i}\right| \leq ?
\end{equation}
where for each $i$ we have:
\begin{equation}
\left| \frac{a_i}{t_i} - \frac{b_i}{s_i} \right| \leq \mathcal{D}_i \leq 1
\end{equation}
$$0 \leq \frac{a_i}{t_i} \leq 1$$
$$0 \leq \frac{b_i}{s_i} \leq 1$$

My conjecture is something $\mathcal{O}(D_i)$ based on some special cases, but generally, I cannot prove it.

Basically, each element of the pair ($a_i/t_i$, $b_i/s_i$) is a normalized value in $[0,1]$, and we have the discrepancy of these two elements. Now we want to bound the discrepancy of the cumulative (not the right term for this, what to use instead?) version of the discrepancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bound is $1$, even if $D_i=0$.  To be specific, let $n=2, \frac {a_1}{t_1}=\frac {b_1}{s_1}=1,  \frac {a_2}{t_2}=\frac {b_2}{s_2}=0$  Now if we let $a_1=t_1=1000$  while $b_1=s_1=1$ and $b_2=0, s_2=1000$ while $a_1=0,t_2=1$ we will have 
$$\begin{equation}
\left|\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{m} a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{m} t_i} - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{m} b_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{m} s_i}\right| =\left|\frac{1000+0}{1000+1}-\frac{1+0}{1+1000}\right|=\frac {999}{1001}
\end{equation}$$
We can clearly get as close to $1$ as we would like by this approach even though $D_i=0$.

Comment: I guess your assumption on $\frac{a_2}{t_2} = \frac{b_2}{s_2} = -1000$ violates the second and third assumptions in the question (where they are required to be normalized to $[0,1]$)

Comment: @saaaz:  the displayed equation does not restrict it to positive values.  The later text does.

Comment: do you have any suggestion on improving the question in terms of clarity?

Comment: You could just put $0 \le$ in front of the last two equations, which seems to fit your intent.  The same argument would say we can achieve $1$ as an upper bound.

Comment: Makes sense, though I guess there is a typo, I suggest this edit: Let $a_1 = t_1 = 1000$, and $b_1 = s_1 = 1$, and $a_2 = b_2 = 0$ and $t_2 = 1$ and $s_2 = 1000$, therefore $\mathcal{D}_1 = \mathcal{D}_2 = 0$.